# Can you use GlVertexAttribPointer without shaders

Tags: opengl

According to the following wiki page:

[OpenGL Wiki Page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlVertexAttribPointer)

It says "One of the requirements is to use shaders.".  Is this true?  To use GlVertexAttribPointer do I have to use shaders?  I'm just starting out in OpenGL and just want to keep things simple for now, without having to introduce shaders at such an early stage of development.  I will be using GLSL eventually, but want to get each feature "working" before adding any new features to my code.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I tried using GLVertexAttribPointer without shaders and it seems to work, so I guess this no longer needs answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true, you need shaders to use generic vertex attributes, if not, how would OpenGL know that attribute 0 is normals, 1 is position and 2 is texture coordinates? There is no API for doing that in the Fixed Function pipeline.

It might work, but that's just luck, not defined behaviour.